# For $G/N$, $(gN)^a=g^aN$ for all integers $a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

For the quotient group $G/N$, $(gN)^a=g^a N$ for all integers $a$.

How do I prove this? Do I proceed with induction? In my class, we've never defined what it means to raise a coset to a power. How is $(gN)^a$ to be interpreted?

Comment: As a corollary, if $a$ is the order of $gN$ in the quotient group, then $a$ is the least value of $n$ such that $g^n\in N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a quotient group, we have that $N$ is a normal subgroup of G.

Let $gN \in G/N$

We know that $(aN)(bN) = (ab)N$ since $N$ is normal.

Then for $(gN)^2 \implies (gN)(gN)=(gg)N=g^2 N$

Then we can generalize for $a$ that $(gN)^a \implies (gN)(gN)...(gN)$
 given $a$ times

$\implies (gN)^a = g^a N$

---

Follow up:

Inverses don't have an important part to play in this proof, although clearly $G/N$ is a group and so $g^{-1} N$ exists.

$(g^{-1} N)(g^{-1} N) = (g^{-1} g^{-1}) N = (g^{-1})^2 N$

So you can see

$(g^{-1} N)^a = (g^{-1})^a N$

Comment: What about the inverse case?

Comment: I don't know that you need to talk about the inverse case.  The proof would be almost identical, just use $g^{-1}$ taken $a$ times

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. What about the case where $a=0$? I know $g=1$ but how do I relate $g^0 N$ to $(gN)^0$

Comment: $N $ is the identity element of the quotient group $G/N $.  It follows immediately.